# Is there a java equivalent of python random._urandom()?

Tags: java, python

If java has a function similar to the function in python called urandom from the random library how can I use it?

Python you would do:

```
import random

random._urandom(1)
```

What can I do in java for this?

Urandom doesn't generate a random numbers, it returns n random bytes suitable for cryptographic use

Comment: Can't be. Urandom doesn't generate an integer

Comment: Look at all methods in [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class it not only generates integers. Also take a look at [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html).

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp that would only be a dupe if the methods also use peripheral data as a source of randomness

Comment: In Python the `random` module is not suitable for cryptographic needs, use the [secrets module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) from Python 3.6 on.

Comment: @PhantomFangs, `urandom` is *not* "suitable for cryptographic use" (except maybe session keys where they won't last very long); `/dev/urandom`, which it uses (or at least originally used), is explicitly faster but weaker than `/dev/random`, which blocks if there isn't enough entropy to give good values and is thus a far better choice for key generation.

Comment: Okay, well, that's python... I asked what to do in java

Comment: Sure, but it influences our understanding of what it actually *is* that you want to do in Java. If you say "I want something like X", it helps if we know which aspects of X you actually care about, and which aspects are incidental (or even misunderstood).

Comment: This is very true

Comment: ...if what you really want is to generate random *bytes* in Java, that question doesn't need to refer to Python or urandom at all.

Comment: It does considering I felt the need to show an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[x];
new Random().nextBytes(bytes);
```

Your array will then be filled with random bytes